# мне нужно вывести MassuvZMin[j] из функции if (Massuv[0][j] < Massuv[0][MinMean])?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Заранне спасибо

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    const int m = 3;
    const int n = 5;
    int Massuv[m][n] = { {1, 3, 32, 13, 8},
                         {5, 7, 9, 5, 1},
                         {2, 33, 4, 9, 6} };
    double MassuvZMin[n] {};
    cout << "First massive's elem Massuv: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if ((Massuv[i][j] % 2) == 0)
            {
                Massuv[i][j] = Massuv[i][j] * Massuv[i][j];
            }
            else if (i % 2 == 1 && j % 2 == 1)
            {
                Massuv[i][j] = Massuv[i][j];
            }
            cout << "\t" << Massuv[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Second massive's elem MassuvZMin: " << endl;
    int MinMean = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            MassuvZMin[j] = Massuv[0][j];
            if (Massuv[0][j] < Massuv[0][MinMean])
            {
                MinMean = j;
                MassuvZMin[j] = cbrt(MinMean);
            }   
            cout << "\t" << MassuvZMin[j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: О какой функции вообще идет речь?

Comment: Самый последний вывод, cout << "\t" << MassuvZMin[j]; При нем выводится MassuvZMin[j] = Massuv[0][j]; Но не MassuvZMin[j] = cbrt(MinMean); с функции if.

Comment: 1)`if` - это не функция, а оператор; 2)Какие значения при выводе вы ожидаете?`cbrt()` ,если не ошибаюсь ф-ция возвращающая кубический корень. У вас MinMean - никогда не изменит своего значения, соответственно, ваш второй массив примет элементы первого столбца и выведет **3** раза подряд одни и те же значения.

Comment: Все верно, мне нужно через второй массив (MassuvZMin) вывести кубический квадрат минимальных значений 1 массива (Massuv) по колонкам, то есть 1, 3, 4, 5, 1.

Comment: Минимальные значения по отношению каких элементов?Лично мне совсем непонятна суть задачи, особенно тогда, когда вы называете переменную **MinMean**. Мин.значение **1 строки = 1;2 строки - 1;3 строки - 2**.

Comment: а что такое «кубический квадрат»? очень интересный термин.

Answer (score 1):

Немного непонятна суть вашей задачи. Покажу как сам понял задачу исходя из исходного кода. Возможно такая реализация вам покажется более логичной.
Немного изменил названия ваших переменных:

1. **Massuv** -> **first_array**
2. **MassuvZMin[n]** -> **second_array[m]**.
3. **MinMean** -> **min_value**.

Обратите внимание на *размерность* второго массива.

```
 int* min_value = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        min_value = min_element(first_array[i], first_array[i] + n);
        second_array[i] = cbrt(*min_value);
        cout << "Min element of " << i + 1 << " row is: " << *min_value
            << ".The cubic root is: " << second_array[i] << endl;
    }
```

Так же не забудьте подключить хедер `#include <algorithm>` для возможности использования шаблона-функции `min_element()`.